How do I call/run a PHP script from a TMS WEB Core app?
I am attempting to call the PHP code from my TMS WEB Core app, but I am unable to do this.
In a normal HTML/PHP website I can navigate to that php file/page or fetch the PHP file and then the code in the php file is executed, but in TMS WEB Core I don't know how to do this.
Does anyone perhaps know how to run PHP code on TMS WEB Core apps?

From what I know tms core apps compile to javascript which runs in the browser. So to call a php script you'd likely have to send an ajax request to a php script - which probably needs to be hosted on another server, because it doesn't seem like the platform would support it. But if you're unclear on the capabilities of the product then in the first instance you should contact the vendor for support

PHP (formerly Pre HTML Processed) is executed on the HTTP server side and the results are sent as response to your browser (HTTP client). You never fetched a PHP file, but instead only queried the result of its execution. Likewise PHP without any HTTP server (neither Delphi, nor TMS WEB Core or your HTTP browser) gets you nowhere. However, you might be interested in PHP4Delphi.
